# Using list of numbers to Select By Attribute in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000358, where-clause

I am trying to use Python to select all records whose attribute (which is a number) in a certain field is within a list.  I cannot get the syntax correct. 
my list is:

```
upstream = [9841978, 9842008, 9841966]
```

I have tried several expressions without success, including:

```
expression = '"COMID" in ' + str(tuple(upstream))
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line     2, in <module>   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7182, in SelectLayerByAttribute     
raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute). 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(catchments, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

Comment: What is your data stored in?  Shapefile, File geodatabase etc.?  What is the field type of the `COMID` field?

Comment: The data are stored are in a feature layer that was created from a feature class that is stored within a file geodatabase.  The COMID field is Long.

Comment: You should always print your SQL expressions to the console.  If you had, it would be more obvious why it's not a valid SQL expression (the `in` operator requires a parenthesis-enclosed list).

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the quote marks around your field name `COMID`

```
expression = 'COMID IN {0}'.format(tuple(upstream))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(catchments, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

Comment: I am receiving the same error (see edits in original post) with this expression.

Comment: @mmoore can you confirm you removed the extra quote marks?  That is the exact error I get if I include the quote marks around the field name, but the expression works if I remove the quote marks

Comment: I have removed them... this is the expression I used, copy and pasted straight from the code that I tried: expression = 'COMID IN {0}'.format(tuple(upstreams))

Comment: @mmoore Odd - I just used the same setup: feature layer from FGDB feature class, selecting on a LONG field type.  Can you include more of your code in your question?

Comment: @mmoore In the code you pasted in the comment your list is 'upstreams', but in the question, and in the answer Midavalo gave, the list is 'upstream'.